# Kinect colorstream and sensor fail when InteractionStream is turned on

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, gesture-recognition

I have made an application which shows the picture from the Kinect camera. I also have a speech recognition method.  I'm trying to add functionality to do an action depending on the hand gesture (open/closed). I've learned that the `InteractionStream` can give me information about this.

I have tried implementing it, but when I run the application, the first lens from the left doesn't work (I don't even see the red light from there, and there is no image on the screen.)

When I comment all code connected with `interactionStream` (implementation/sending frames etc.), the camera works properly. The light shines and I can see my sad face.

Is possible that these streams work at the same time? Is this just a limitation of the Kinect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. When you will be in this same situation, you need to copy two files

- KinectInteraction170_64.dll
- KinectInteraction170_32.dll

from the two folders in Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.7.0\Redist. Then, you need to paste them in the nameofyourproject/debug/bin folder. 
I also add them as existing item in the visual studio.